# Braintree Marketplace API - In Sandbox Account?

Tags: braintree

I want to test the Braintree Marketplace API in the sandbox mode. I have already created the sandbox account and using the node.js SDK.

I am referring the docs from here : https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/marketplace/onboarding/node

Below is my Node code :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    merchantAccountParams = {
  individual: {
    firstName: "Jane",
    lastName: "Doe",
    email: "jane@14ladders.com",
    phone: "5553334444",
    dateOfBirth: "1981-11-19",
    ssn: "456-45-4567",
    address: {
      streetAddress: "111 Main St",
      locality: "Chicago",
      region: "IL",
      postalCode: "60622"
    }
  },
  business: {
    legalName: "Jane's Ladders",
    dbaName: "Jane's Ladders",
    taxId: "98-7654321",
    address: {
      streetAddress: "111 Main St",
      locality: "Chicago",
      region: "IL",
      postalCode: "60622"
    }
  },
  funding: {
    descriptor: "Blue Ladders",
    //destination: MerchantAccount.FundingDestination.Bank,
        destination:"Demo Bank",
        email: "funding@blueladders.com",
    mobilePhone: "5555555555",
    accountNumber: "1123581321",
    routingNumber: "071101307"
  },
  tosAccepted: true,
  masterMerchantAccountId: "14ladders_marketplace",
  id: "blue_ladders_store"
};

gateway.merchantAccount.create(merchantAccountParams, function (err, result) {
        res.send(result.success);
});

});
```

The above code always return false.I am wondering that can we even test this with the sandbox or not? or am i missing something ?

Anyone face this issue before please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to [contact support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sup>

The destination parameter is not looking for the name of a bank, it is looking for a literal string that indicates if the account should be funded using a `bank`, `email`, or `mobile_phone`. You can use these strings directly, but we suggest you use the [constant references](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_node/blob/8cd001d48eb798f469d465cf216ab68d1aad02a0/src/braintree/merchant_account.coffee#L9-L12), because it makes the code cleaner and protects against future changes.

You can read more about the details of the different funding destination types in our [guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/marketplace/onboarding/node#funding-parameters) and [reference](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/merchant-account/create/node#funding.destination).

Comment: Hello Pblesi , thanks for your answer. now i am getting the invalid merchantAccountId error , i am passing the merchant account id which i am getting that from Settings > Processing > Merchant Accounts. please suggest what is missing?

Comment: @DhirajKarkera I would look at the particular validation error that you are getting back. It may be that the merchant account is not set up as a Marketplace master merchant. If this does not resolve your issue, please reach out to our [support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) for further assistance.

Comment: Yes right @Pblesi i just found out that the sandbox account that i had created was not the US Account , in order to use the Market place API you need to have the account created as the USA Account. thanks  for all your help.

Comment: @Dhiraj, how did u know that it is not US account?